# Understanding EasyList

Tags: adblock

I am trying to understand the different rules of [EasyList](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt) of Adblock Plus but have not been able to find a definitive guide. Could someone point me to the right place or describe the different rules and symbols, e.g., #, ##, ###, $, @@, ||, ^, and so on? When is the matching done with url, and when is it done with `class` and `id` attributes? Which rules define whitelists and which ones define blacklists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it at https://adblockplus.org/en/filters. The page describes the different types of filters as well as tips for creating them.